# Why is my asp.net reset button not functioning as intended?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web application which uses SQL 2008 as its database.  I have a reset button which should allow the user to click, and then perform another search.

When the user clicks this reset button, it clears the onscreen forms and drop down menus, but any subsequent searches do not pull up a gridview but instead just blank space.  Ive included my code below.  Please let me know if im missing anything

aspx.cs

```
        protected void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList2.Enabled = true;
        DropDownList4.Enabled = true;
        chkImpacted.Enabled = true;
        chkSupporting.Enabled = true;
        Button1.Visible = false;
        GridView1.Visible = false;
        DropDownList2.ClearSelection();
        DropDownList4.ClearSelection();
        chkImpacted.Checked = false;
        chkSupporting.Checked = false;
    }
```

aspx.cs

```
<asp:Button ID="btnReset" runat="server" Text="Reset" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial"
 Font-Size="9px" ForeColor="Black" OnClick="btnReset_Click" />
```

The reset clears the field, but I have to refresh the page before another search can be performed.  I have other reset buttons with similar coding that are properly working.  Any ideas?

Adding button search code:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch2" runat="server" Text="Search" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial"
Font-Size="9px" ForeColor="Black" OnClick="btnSearch2_Click" />
```

aspx.cs

```
        protected void btnSearch2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FillGrid1();
        Button1.Visible = true;
        DropDownList2.Enabled = false;
        DropDownList4.Enabled = false;
        chkImpacted.Enabled = false;
        chkSupporting.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: It's not important, but there are many different types of "sql databases", SQL Server (microsoft) is the one you probably mean (there are others like MySql, Sqlite, ...)

Comment: You say: "...subsequent searches do not pull up a gridview but instead just blank space." And you have `GridView1.Visible = false;`

Comment: What's the purpose of `GridView1.Visible = false;` in your reset function?

Comment: That clears the previous gridview which contains the results of the previous search.  That function works, but then doesnt allow me to run a new search after, the blank area just stays.  Ive added the search button code as well.

Comment: So you are making the grid invisible, but do not make it visible again when you press the search button. That could be causing this because visibility is stored in the ViewState (if it's not disabled).

Comment: Agreed.  When you hit the "Search" button, you need to set `GridView1.Visible` to True again.

Comment: Oh my word I feel like such an idiot.  How did I not see that.  Thank you guys so much :)

Comment: One of you put this as an answer so you get credit please.

Comment: Fine, guess *I'll* take credit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `GridView1.Visible` *back* to True when you search again, as the False value is being persisted through Viewstate:

```
protected void btnSearch2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FillGrid1();
    Button1.Visible = true;
    GridView1.Visible = true; // <-- Add this
    DropDownList2.Enabled = false;
    DropDownList4.Enabled = false;
    chkImpacted.Enabled = false;
    chkSupporting.Enabled = false;
}
```